# Dynamically populating spinner using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, android-spinner

Here what am looking for is need to populate spinner which is a json response from rest service using retrofit . After a long research i cant find any samples on this can anyone share some sample based on this this would be very useful for me thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first create theretrofitapi interface

```
/**
 * reCreated by goodlife on 1/11/2016.
 */
import java.util.List;


import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.Field;
import retrofit.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.POST;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/5/2015.
 */
public interface RetrofitInternetApi {

    //@FormUrlEncoded, we have to write this if we want to send post data to the server.
    //@POST, because we are using an HTTP Post request we have written this.
    // Inside it we have the URL of the script that will be receiving the post request.
    // Note that the URL is excluding the root URL. And we have defined the root URL  in our MainActivity.
    //@Field(“key”) String variable inside key we have to write what we have written inside $_POST[‘key’] in our script.
    // And we have to specify it for all the values we are going to send.

    //Callback<Response> callback it is also inside the retrofit library. It will receive the output from the server.

    //But this is only an interface and the method is abstract.
    //We will define the method inside fetchDepartmentName() method that is declared inside MainActivity.java.

    @GET("/getDepartmentName.php")
    public void getDepartmentName(Callback<List<DepartmentNoRealm>> response);

}
```

then create the function

```
  private void fetchDepartmentName(){
//Creating a rest adapter
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
                .build();

        //Creating an object of our api interface
        RetrofitInternetApi retrofitInternetApi = restAdapter.create(RetrofitInternetApi.class);
            //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
            final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);



            //Defining the method
            retrofitInternetApi.getDepartmentName(new Callback<List<DepartmentNoRealm>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<DepartmentNoRealm> list, Response response) {
                    //Dismissing the loading progressbar
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Log.d("JSON  LIST",list.toString());
                    //Storing the data in our list
                    departmentNoRealmList = list;

                    //Calling a method to show the list
                      showListinSpinner();            }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //you can handle the errors here
                }
            });
        }
```

then create a class model

```
package myafya.safaricom.co.ke.myafya.model.realm;

/**
 * Created by 001557 on 1/13/2016.
 */
public class DepartmentNoRealm {
    public int departmentID;
    public String departmentName;
    public String departmentURLimage;

    public int getDepartmentID() {
        return departmentID;
    }

    public void setDepartmentID(int departmentID) {
        this.departmentID = departmentID;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public String getDepartmentURLimage() {
        return departmentURLimage;
    }

    public void setDepartmentURLimage(String departmentURLimage) {
        this.departmentURLimage = departmentURLimage;
    }
}
```

now the code showList in Spinner

```
//Our method to show list
    private void showListinSpinner(){
        //String array to store all the book names
        String[] items = new String[departmentNoRealmList.size()];

        //Traversing through the whole list to get all the names
        for(int i=0; i<departmentNoRealmList.size(); i++){
            //Storing names to string array
            items[i] = departmentNoRealmList.get(i).getDepartmentName();
        }

        //Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        //setting adapter to spinner
        spinnerDepartments.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Creating an array adapter for list view

    }
```

Then SHARE IT AND MAKE IT EASY

MY JSON WAS

```
[
  {
    "departmentID": "1",
    "departmentName": "Enterprise Business Unit (EBU)",
    "departmentURLimage": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKOZmGNAA08NbHwRJrloAouWqs6r4x7BGXY4k-ULWiHuPEobHI"
  },
  {
    "departmentID": "2",
    "departmentName": "Consumer Business Unit (CBU)",
    "departmentURLimage": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ0IAFhZ52KiG_0ck5VbBxweZWf_MEA9eRmgHAEr6CG-rUG_a2QEQ"
  }
]
```