# How to add data into Spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

In my application I want show some data from server into Spinner.
For Spinner I use this library : https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner
**My Json :**

```
"stars": [
      {
        "id": 105076,
        "name": "Eleanor Tomlinson",
        "character": null,
        "imageUrl": "http://example.com/cpanel/uploads/Celebrities/105076/thumb2-SK4MPEGW09.jpg",
        "userReview": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 10127,
        "name": "Aidan Turner",
        "character": null,
        "imageUrl": "http://example.com/cpanel/uploads/Celebrities/10127/thumb2-KL9G4TNGW2.jpg",
        "userReview": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 21340,
        "name": "Gabriella Wilde",
        "character": null,
        "imageUrl": "http://example.com/cpanel/uploads/Celebrities/21340/thumb2-UD5HJ2EICN.jpg",
        "userReview": ""
      }
    ]
```

For connect to server I use `Retrofit` Library and write **below codes :**

```
final SerialDetailSendData sendData = new SerialDetailSendData();
sendData.setSeriesID(serialID);

InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
Call<SeriesDetailResponse> call = api.getSeriesDetail(sendData);

call.enqueue(new Callback<SeriesDetailResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SeriesDetailResponse> call, Response<SeriesDetailResponse> response) {
        if (response.body().getData() != null) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_hint_item,
                    ???);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
            SerialReview_CastSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            SerialReview_CastProgress.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SeriesDetailResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

But I don't know how can I add names from stars class into ArrayAdapter for set in Spinner.

```
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_hint_item,
                    ???);
```

Comment: Why don't you make an  `ArrayAdapter<SeriesDetailResponse>`?
 https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 0):

First create the `ArrayList` of retrieve data from api.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayList.add("Item1");
arrayList.add("Item2");
arrayList.add("Item3");
```

And create a `ArrayAdapter` of the data.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList);
spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: You have pojo class right. `arrayList.add().response.getData().getItem ...` Some thing like this.

Comment: @Kir Full code? You don't need retrofit to add data to an adapter

Comment: @Kir Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936573/dynamically-populating-spinner-using-retrofit . I think this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be adding to the adapter in the callback, not creating one as it is less efficient in object creation.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

call.enqueue(new Callback<SeriesDetailResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SeriesDetailResponse> call, Response<SeriesDetailResponse> response) {
        SeriesDetailResponse body = response.body();
        List<Star> stars = body.getStars();

        adapter.clear();
        for (Star star : stars) {
            adapter.add(star.toString());
        }

        progress.hide();
    }
```

If you had a `List<String>` with `ArrayAdapter<String>` or used an `ArrayAdapter<Star>`, you could shorten that loop with `adapter.addAll()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
    final SerialDetailSendData sendData = new SerialDetailSendData();
    sendData.setSeriesID(serialID);

    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<SeriesDetailResponse> call = api.getSeriesDetail(sendData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<SeriesDetailResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SeriesDetailResponse> call, Response<SeriesDetailResponse> response) {
            if (response.body().getData() != null) {
                ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getData().getStars().size(); i++) {
                    arrayList.add(response.body().getData().getStars().get(i).getName());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_hint_item, arrayList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
                SerialReview_CastSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                SerialReview_CastProgress.hide();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SeriesDetailResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't call `response.body()` more than once

Comment: @cricket_007, why my friend? one call response.body() for get size and Twice call for get star's names

Comment: Because according to OkHTTP and retrofit documentation, it throws an error.

Comment: I use this code any more and not show me any error and work very good!

Comment: Okay, maybe it's `string()`. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240 Still! calling the same method to get the response body many times is pointless